# Google NTP server sometimes not giving response

Tags: java, android, ntp

I am trying to implement a Google(time.google.com) NTP server to get current internet time for an app.
Sometimes it's work and sometimes not it gives me an NTP server not found an error.

```
 public static Date getNtpServerDate(final String timeServerHost) throws IOException {
    try {
        TimeInfo timeInfo = null;
        final NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
        timeClient.setDefaultTimeout(NTP_SERVER_TIMEOUT_MS);

        final InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("time.google.com");
        if (inetAddress != null) {
            timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
            if (timeInfo != null) {
                // TODO: which time to use?
                final long serverTime = timeInfo.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime();
                //long serverTime = timeInfo.getReturnTime();
                final Date ntpDate = new Date(serverTime);
                return ntpDate;
            }
        }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new IOException("Unable to get NTP server time.", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is the code which I am using to get NTP time
Please help me to solve this.please can someone help me?

Comment: are you sure its not a network issue rather than actually the NTP server being unavailable?

Comment: @TharakaDevinda Yes, I am sure about it. It is not the network issue

Comment: If the NTP_SERVER_TIMEOUT_MS value is too small then the call may timeout. Increase value of the timeout to give the call more time to fetch the time. The call is asynchronous and it must wait for the server to send an NTP UDP packet.